# CSS not working properly

Tags: html, css

This is probably a really simple problem but I'm getting this weird error.

I added my main.css to my main.php

but the CSS classes are not working unless I make a duplicate...

something like:

```
.myClass {
    //empty
}

.myClass {
    //actual properties
}
```

if I delete the first Empty class declaration, the css class is not applied.... like if it's empty.

Have you ever encounter this error?

Comment: you probably have some sort of error in the line above that statement, which causes it to process that first line incorrectly.

Comment: What Andi said, make sure you have all of your closing brackets in place. Try to recreate this issue in fiddle, doing so may show where the error is happening.

Comment: I think you should check css file in an another project with a page

Comment: Building on top of the previous comments; a good way to check your CSS is check the console of the developer tools of your browser. Modern browsers will have functionality to display CSS errors.

Comment: If you still can't figure it out, post the encompassing CSS code.

Comment: @andi yep, that did it, I hade a comment before with '//' , I just realized that this is not the way of commenting in CSS :P

Comment: i dont like ppl that downvote a question without saying why :P

Comment: @andi post your answer and I ll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, will post as answer:

"you probably have some sort of error in the line above that statement, which causes it to process that first line incorrectly."

"@andi yep, that did it, I hade a comment before with '//' , I just realized that this is not the way of commenting in CSS :P"